# Controlling a circuit board from my PC

Tags: pcb, interface, robotics

I am planning for a project I want to make that involves a custom pcb. The board is fairly simple. It has a 4 bit input. But I need to do advanced calculations from my computer to determine what the inputs would be. What is the best way to command from a java program to a 4 bit circuit board. I imagine some sort of USB adapter but I really don’t know.

Comment: FTDI has USB to serial bridges which also have a number of GPIO which you can control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use serial communication on your board and use an RS232 to USB converter (FTDI) to communicate with the PC.
Also, you can implement serial to USB communication directly on the board using ICs and give a micro usb port output to connect to the computer.
(A UART to USB bridge will be needed, most vendors have those, TI has some, [like this](http://www.ti.com/product/TUSB3410)). 
Using the FTDI would be easier, but you can design the UART - USB communication, if you're looking for a challenge.

Comment: Dont some FTDIs have GPIOs too?

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems like the answer I️ was looking for although I️ now have some terms to look up. And this is one of the few times where I’m actually looking for a practical solution and not a challenge lol.